# Why does Groovy execute() hang?

Tags: scala, groovy

I have the following Groovy script:

```
#!/opt/groovy-1.8.6/bin/groovy

final env = null // []

final command = ["./setter-for-catan.scala"]
final process = command.execute(env, null)

println (['echo', '********************** 0'].execute(env, null).text)
final stdout = process.inputStream
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout))
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println ("Stdout: " + line);
}
```

and the following Scala script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export SCALA_HOME=/opt/scala-2.10.1

echo '********************* 1' "$0" "$@"
${SCALA_HOME}/bin/scala -version 2>&1
exec ${SCALA_HOME}/bin/scala "$0" "$@" 2>&1
!#

println("******************* 2")
```

Calling the Groovy script outputs:

```
********************** 0

Stdout: ********************* 1 ./setter-for-catan.scala
Stdout: Scala code runner version 2.10.1 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
Stdout: ******************* 2
```

If `env` is defined as `[]`, the Groovy script hangs with the following output:

```
********************** 0

Stdout: ********************* 1 ./setter-for-catan.scala
Stdout: Scala code runner version 2.10.1 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

What's going on and what needs to be done so that `execute()` doesn't hang when `env` is an `Array`?

Comment: You could run `strace -f your-first-script` to see what is happening when the process hangs.

Comment: What happens if you run `env -i ./setter-for-catan.scala`?

Comment: @EmilSit, that causes the script to hang, too. What needs to be done to specify that it ought to inherit the environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JAVA_HOME isn't being inherited by the Scala script so it needs to be defined.

One way to do it would be in the Scala script:

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home
export SCALA_HOME=/opt/scala-2.10.1

echo '********************* 1' "$0" "$@"
${SCALA_HOME}/bin/scala -version 2>&1
exec ${SCALA_HOME}/bin/scala "$0" "$@" 2>&1
!#
```

Another way would be to do it in the Groovy script:

```
final env = ['JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/Home']
```